# multicol list spacing before and after section titles

Tags: spacing, multicol, enumitem

How can I get consistent spacing before and after an `itemize` environment inside a `multicols` environment when the list is immediately after or immediately before the start of a section?

[image]

The list in Foo2 is an `enumitem` list and the spacing before and after the list seems to match the spacing before and after the text in Foo1.

The list in Foo3 is the same `enumitem` list but enclosed in a `multicols` environment.  There is way too much vertical space before and after the two-column list.

The list in Foo4 is the same as Foo3 except `\multicolsep` is set to 0pt.  The space before is still too much but not as bad, and there is now too little space after the list.

How do I fix this to get consistent spacing?

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[vmargin=1em,hmargin=0.25in+1em,papersize={2in,2.7in}]{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\normalfont\large\scshape}{}{0pt}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing*{\section}{-0.25in}{*0.25}{*0.25}[-0.25in]

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\SetEnumitemKey{twocol}{
  before=\raggedcolumns\begin{multicols}{2},
  after=\end{multicols},
}
\SetEnumitemKey{twocol0}{
  before=\raggedcolumns\setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}\begin{multicols}{2},
  after=\end{multicols},
}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*,nosep,}

\begin{document}%
\section{Foo1}Aj%
\section{Foo2}\begin{itemize}\item{}Aj\end{itemize}%
\section{Foo3}\begin{itemize}[twocol,]\item{}Aj\item{}Aj\end{itemize}%
\section{Foo4}\begin{itemize}[twocol0,]\item{}Aj\item{}Aj\end{itemize}%
\section{Foo5}Aj%
\end{document}
```

Versions:

- `multicol 2014/08/24 v1.8g  multicolumn formatting (FMi)`
- `enumitem 2011/09/28 v3.5.2 Customized lists`

Answer (score 1):

If you need `multicolumn` only  to have an on line `itemize`  environment, I suggest another approach, based on the `shortlst` package. You'll find it on CTAN, but it's not in any distribution for licensing reasons.

I define a `tabitemize` environment, for column-wise displayed items; the number of columns is controlled by an `nc` key (3 by default). I think the following code gives what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[vmargin=1em,hmargin=0.25in+1em,papersize={2in,2.7in}]{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\normalfont\large\scshape}{}{0pt}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing*{\section}{-0.25in}{*0.25}{*0.25}[-0.25in]

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\SetEnumitemKey{twocol}{
  before=\raggedcolumns\begin{multicols}{2},
  after=\end{multicols},
}
\SetEnumitemKey{twocol0}{
  before=\raggedcolumns\setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}\begin{multicols}{2},
  after=\end{multicols},
}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*,nosep,}


    \usepackage{shortlst, xkeyval}

    \makeatletter
    \newcounter{ncol}
    \define@key{mcl}{nc}[3]{\setcounter{ncol}{#1}}%% 3 columns by default
    \newenvironment{tabitemize}[1][]{%
    \setkeys{mcl}{nc,#1}
    \settowidth{\labelwidth}{\textbullet}
    \setlength{\leftmargini}{\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep\relax}%[1][3]
    \setlength{\shortitemwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth/\value{ncol}-\labelwidth-2\labelsep\relax}%
          \begin{shortitemize}}%
    {\end{shortitemize}
     \vspace*{\dimexpr-\topsep-\partopsep\relax
     }%

\begin{document}%

\section{Foo1}Aj%
\section{Foo2}\begin{itemize}\item{}Aj\end{itemize}%
\section{Foo3}\begin{tabitemize}[nc = 2]\item{}Aj\item{}Aj\end{tabitemize}%
\section{Foo4}\begin{tabitemize}[nc = 2]\item{}Aj\item{}Aj\end{tabitemize}%
\section{Foo5}Aj%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  This is closer to what I want, but it looks like there's still extra whitespace after the multicolumn list, and I lose all of the nifty `enumitem` features.

Comment: @Richard Hansen: Unfortunately there is no equivalent to `shortitemize/enumerate` in `enumitem`. I modified the code to remove the vertical spacing after the list. See my updated answer.

Comment: +1 thanks for fixing the trailing space.  I'm curious as to why that negative space is required.  What's adding it?

Comment: @Richard Hansen: I don't know the details of LaTeX internals, but the definition of `shortitemize` ends with `\endlist`, so I suspected this might add the classical vertical spacing at the end of ordinary lists. I tested, and it worked…